# I have this error when people upload their cv to my site

Tags: wordpress

When someone goes to upload their cv to my jobs board they seem to get this error once the press apply.

```
Warning: fopen(/home/freelanc/public_html/wp-content/uploads/cv/2012/01/WebSiteBrief.doc)     [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestudents.co.uk/html/wp-content/themes/freelance_v2/inc/php/swift/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php on line 131

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Unable to open file for reading [/home/freelanc/public_html/wp-content/uploads/cv/2012/01/WebSiteBrief.doc]' in /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestudents.co.uk/html/wp-content/themes/freelance_v2/inc/php/swift/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php:133 Stack trace: #0 /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestudents.co.uk/html/wp-content/themes/freelance_v2/inc/php/swift/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php(77): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->_getReadHandle() #1 /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestudents.co.uk/html/wp-content/themes/freelance_v2/inc/php/swift/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php(660): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->read(8192) #2 /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestudents.co.uk/html/wp-content/themes/freelance_v2/inc/php/swift/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php(337): Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->_readStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream)) #3 /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestud in /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestudents.co.uk/html/wp-content/themes/freelance_v2/inc/php/swift/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php on line 133
```

I think the problem is somewhere to do with this.

```
 /** Get the resource for reading */
   private function _getReadHandle()
 {
if (!isset($this->_reader))
{
  if (!$this->_reader = fopen($this->_path, 'rb'))
  {
    throw new Swift_IoException(
      'Unable to open file for reading [' . $this->_path . ']'
      );
  }
  fseek($this->_reader, $this->_offset, SEEK_SET);
}
return $this->_reader;
  }
```

I changed the code to this adding this **($path = realpath('uploads/'))*

```
/** Get the resource for reading */
 private function _getReadHandle()
 {
if (!isset($this->_reader))
{
  if (!$this->_reader = fopen($path = realpath('uploads/')
  {
    throw new Swift_IoException(
      'Unable to open file for reading [' . $this->_path . ']'
      );
  }
  fseek($this->_reader, $this->_offset, SEEK_SET);
}
return $this->_reader;
```

but now I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: What do you try to do? I see that i can download freelancestudents.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/cv/2012/01/WebSiteBrief.doc and see it. Do you have an upload form for cv's and that is not working?

Comment: How did you manage to find that file! and the form is working fine if you send a message without a CV. The problem only occurs one you attach a cv and try to send it.

Comment: It is in your code up there :) `public_html/wp-content/uploads/cv/2012/01/WebSiteBrief.doc` and the domain is from here `nfs/c08/h02/mnt/115857/domains/freelancestudents.co.uk/html/wp-content/t`. Apparently the form has not set a proper upload directory.

Comment: Do you have a configuration file of this plugin? Can you trace the configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure. Where would I find this...please see my edit above.

Comment: Yes because you missed a `)` ... should be `fopen($path = realpath('uploads/'))`

Comment: Now I get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Comment: yes because you did not close it from `private function _getReadHandle()`

Comment: this is very frusting..i'm not much of a programmer. ..i think i closed it and now get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW ....would you mind adding me on Skype so could take me though it.... It would be a massive help... amoses89

Answer (score 0):

Set the directory permissions to 777 for *wp-content/uploads* recursively.

Wp is trying to make a new folder for every month if you have checked the uploads to be organised by date. Once you make a new upload he tries to make a new folder and ha cannot.

Solved: the website was moved to some other host but had absolute paths set to old hosting.